# Date Format Java Decimal Days to Days and Hour

Tags: java

I have days in format of decimal like 22.5 days
I want to convert it like 22 days 12 hours using java

Need help in above question.
Thank you in advance

Comment: [What have you tried please ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Why not writing a little method of your own to make this?

Comment: @user1328994 if you'd have given an example of what you have tried you would have got a better response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat but plain math is likely to be simpler.

```
double days = 22.5;
long hours = Math.round(days * 24);
String text = hours/24 + " days, " + hours % 24 +" hours.";
```

Adding minutes and second you can do.

```
double days = 22.5;
long seconds = Math.round(days * 86400);
String text = seconds/86400 + " days, "
           + seconds / 3600 % 24 + " hours, "
           + seconds / 60 % 60   + " minutes, "
           + seconds % 60        + " second.";
```

Using SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' days, 'hh' hours'");
SDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String text = SDF.format(new Date(Math.round(days * 86400000)));
```

Note: SimpleDateFormat is only useful up to 31 days. ;)

Comment: +1 really nice solution :) i am deleting my **odd** solution :P

Comment: I think you meant `String text = seconds/...` in the second part instead of `hours`.

Comment: I was wonderting if we can format struts 2 text in above date format using <s:text name="format.myDateOption"><s:param value ="decimal date value from struts2 stack"/></s:text>? In such case what could be formatting string in properties file ? Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: I can't say I have ever used struts. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is a vague answer but just to demonstrate you that it is very simple:

```
int a=22.5,hr,days;
int days=22.5;
float t1=22.5;
(t1-days)*24=...
```

:)